# Why is DHT11 Sensor not giving correct readings on Arduino Mega?

Tags: c++, sensors, arduino-ide

[This is the outcome I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdMB5.png)

#include <SimpleDHT.h>

// for DHT11,

//      VCC: 5V or 3V

//      GND: GND

//      DATA: 2

int pinDHT11 = 2;

SimpleDHT11

dht11(pinDHT11);

void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

// start working...

Serial.println("=================================");

Serial.println("Sample DHT11...");

// read without samples.

byte temperature = 0;

byte humidity = 0;

int err = SimpleDHTErrSuccess;

if ((err = dht11.read(&temperature, &humidity, NULL)) != SimpleDHTErrSuccess) {

```
Serial.print("Read DHT11 failed, err="); Serial.print(SimpleDHTErrCode(err));

Serial.print(","); Serial.println(SimpleDHTErrDuration(err)); delay(1000);

return;
```

}

Serial.print("Sample OK: ");

Serial.print((int)temperature); Serial.print(" *C, ");

Serial.print((int)humidity); Serial.println(" H");

// DHT11 sampling rate is 1HZ.

delay(1500);

}

Comment: This is a C++ program, not Java.

Comment: Yeah my bad I dont know why it reccomended me java

Comment: If you are using arduino, the possibility is that the problem came from the circuit. Check your connection of the circuit and if possible, provide the connection diagram and photo to reproduce the error.

Comment: To be able to answer your question, you should provide the SimpleDHT.h, too since DHT driver  headerfile differs from vendor to ventor.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. It turns out the problem were the first two DHT11 sensors we tried, it seems like they were faulty. We tested a third sensor that was brand new and it work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the DHT11 would not work was because the sesnors were actualy faulty. There was nothing wrong with our code or wirings. We figured this out by trying a third DHT11 sensor which was brand new and just out of the packet. This time it worked and gave us accurate realistic readings.